# JS list of dictionaries, get first value by condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, dictionary, object

Given a list of dictionaries in JS, I want to get the first one that is enabled and not deleted.

The dictionary will look like this:

```
objects= [{'name':'a', 'width': 100, 'deleted': true, 'enabled': true},
          {'name':'b', 'width': 200, 'deleted': false, 'enabled': false},
          {'name':'c', 'width': 300, 'deleted': false, 'enabled': true},
          {'name':'d', 'width': 400, 'deleted': true, 'enabled': true},
```

I used to take the first one by using `objects[0]` but now I need to tkae the deleted and enabled in consideration. How can I get the first relevant value? so the results should be `{'name':'c', 'width': 300, 'deleted': false, 'enabled': true}`

Comment: `objects.find(entry=>entry.enabled && !entry.deleted)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), if you want to find the first object that match the find condition in the array.

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), If you want to find all the objects that match the filter condition in the array.

```js
objects= [{'name':'a', 'width': 100, 'deleted': true, 'enabled': true},
          {'name':'b', 'width': 200, 'deleted': false, 'enabled': false},
          {'name':'c', 'width': 300, 'deleted': false, 'enabled': true},
          {'name':'d', 'width': 400, 'deleted': true, 'enabled': true}
          ];
          
var findOne = objects.find(x => !x.deleted && x.enabled);
console.log(findOne);

var findMany = objects.filter(x => !x.deleted && x.enabled);
console.log(findMany);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Find Method**

You can use the [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find the first element that matches a given condition.

```
const solution = objects.find(o => o.enabled && !o.deleted);
```